# Is there a way to get a symbol of a non-printable character?

Tags: c#, char, ascii, non-printing-characters

I want to find a way to get a symbol of a non-printable character in c# (e.g. `"SOH"` for start of heading and `"BS"` for backspace). Any ideas?

**Edit:** I don't need to visualize a byte value of a non-printable character but it's code as shown here https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html

Example would be `"NUL"` for `0x00`, `"SOH"` for `0x01` etc.

Comment: I'm thinking that you may need to use a specific font.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137947/print-non-printable-characters-in-a-given-string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, probably, are looking for a kind of *string dump* in order to *visualize* control characters. You can do it with a help of *Regular Expressions* where `\p{Cc}` matches control symbol:

```
using Systen.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string source = "BEL \u0007 then CR + LF  \r\n SOH \u0001 \0\0";

// To get control characters visible, we match them and
// replace with their codes
string result = Regex.Replace(
  source, @"\p{Cc}", 
  m => $"[Control: 0x{(int)m.Value[0]:x4}]");

// Let's have a look:

// Initial string 
Console.WriteLine(source);
Console.WriteLine();
// Control symbols visualized
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
BEL   then CR + LF  
 SOH  

BEL [Control: 0x0007] then CR + LF  [Control: 0x000d][Control: 0x000a] SOH [Control: 0x0001] [Control: 0x0000][Control: 0x0000]
```

**Edit:** If you want to visualize in a *different* way, you shoud edit lambda

```
m => $"[Control: 0x{(int)m.Value[0]:x4}]"
```

For instance:

```
    static string[] knownCodes = new string[] {
      "NULL", "SOH", "STX", "ETX", "EOT", "ENQ",
      "ACK",  "BEL", "BS", "HT", "LF", "VT",
      "FF", "CR", "SO", "SI", "DLE", "DC1", "DC2",
      "DC3", "DC4", "NAK", "SYN", "ETB", "CAN",
      "EM", "SUB", "ESC", "FS", "GS", "RS", "US",
    };

    private static string StringDump(string source) {
      if (null == source)
        return source;

      return Regex.Replace(
        source, 
       @"\p{Cc}", 
        m => {
          int code = (int)(m.Value[0]);

          return code < knownCodes.Length 
            ? $"[{knownCodes[code]}]" 
            : $"[Control 0x{code:x4}]";  
        });
    }
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.WriteLine(StringDump(source));
```

**Outcome:**

```
BEL [BEL] then CR + LF  [CR][LF] SOH [SOH] [NULL][NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks for an idea but this is just a visualized byte value of a character. I need an actual code of a character as shown here https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html

Comment: @Alex Kovaliv: if you want to visualize in different way, you should change the lambda. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio just displaying the SOH character (U+0001) for example and than encode it like this:

> var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("☺");

And now you can do whatever you like with it. For Backspace use U+232B

Comment: I don't need a byte value of a character. I want to know an actual character (code) of a non-printable character as shown in this table https://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html